# Has anyone successfully used the Salesforce and Amazon Connect Lens lambda for storing Sentiment to Salesforce - PostCallAnalysisTriggerFunction

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

I am getting 403 when storing post call data to the end point /telephony/v1/voiceCalls/{vendorCallKey}/postConversationEvents this relates to Amazon Connect Contact Lens data - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_developer_guide.meta/voice_developer_guide/voice_rest_post-call_conversation_event.html

Followed all the docs and used the OOTB code but still no luck.

Tested the code in postman and same problem.